# error converting qt file with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I did a search and found what I thought would be the answer to my question but it seems like I've already done the recommended 64 bit PyQt version initially

So I downloaded Qt from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ ...not sure if it's 32 or 64 bit and I'm guessing this is where the issue is as I already have the 64 bit PyQt.

I tried to convert my .ui file to a .py and got the following error:

```
C:\Users\name\Desktop>pyuic4 -o xdrip_gui.py xdrip_gui.ui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 31, in <module>
from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any ideas on the fix knowing I already downloaded the 64bit .exe PyQt from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

Comment: Are you using 64-bit python?

Comment: Yes. Using 64 bit python.